# How to merge Bazaar patches into a Git repository?

Tags: git, merge, patch, bazaar

How can I merge patches from a bzr repository hosted on launchpad into a self hosted git repository?

```
bzr merge lp:ubuntu/trusty-proposed/chewmail
```

I tryed this but it wont work because my git repo is not a bzr repository.

Thanks.

Comment: If `bzr` is able to to export your work as a patchset (a series of patch files) just do that and then apply them using either `git apply` or `git am`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the man page for `git-remote-bzr`.

Oh, I'm sorry, it's not from the main `git` package. Here's the homepage link: https://launchpad.net/bzr-git You may check if it exists in your distribution repository.